# Python treating all instances of an object as the same

Tags: python, instance, pymunk

I'm making a game with pygame and pymunk as a physics engine. I'm trying to kill a bullet whenever it hits a player or goes past its lifetime.

When I tried to space.remove(self.shape) and the second bullet hits the player, it gives me an "AssertionError: shape not in space, already removed. I simply changed it to teleport the bullets away, and then learned of the real error.

When I have more than one bullet in the space and a bullet hits the enemy player, all the current bullets teleport away, which means that when I tried to remove one bullet, it called the remove on all the bullets and thats why I had the initial error.

However the problem still remains that one bullet is being treated as every bullet.

Why is something that should be a non-static variable being called as a static variable?
I even tried to use deepcopy to see if that fixed it, but to no avail

This is my chunk of code, apologies since I don't know what is needed to understand it.

The key parts are most likely the Bullet class, the shoot() function in the Player class, and the drawBulletCollision() function

```
# PyGame template.
 
# Import modules.
import sys, random, math, time, copy
from typing import List

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import mixer
import pymunk
import pymunk.pygame_util
from pymunk.shapes import Segment
from pymunk.vec2d import Vec2d

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44110, -16, 2, 512)
mixer.init()

# Set up the window.
width, height = 1440, 640
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

bg = pygame.image.load("space.png")

def draw_bg():
  screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

#load sounds
#death_fx = pygame.mixer.Sound("")
#death_fx.set_volume(0.25)

shoot_fx = mixer.Sound("shot.wav")
shoot_fx.set_volume(0.25)

#mixer.music.load("video.mp3")
#mixer.music.play()
#time.sleep(2)
#mixer.music.stop()

#gun_mode_fx = pygame.mixer.Sound("")
#gun_mode_fx.set_volume(0.25)

#thrust_mode_fx = pygame.mixer.Sound("")
#thrust_mode_fx.set_volume(0.25)

collision_fx = mixer.Sound("thump.wav")
collision_fx.set_volume(0.25)

ship_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

space = pymunk.Space()
space.gravity = 0, 0
space.damping = 0.6
draw_options = pymunk.pygame_util.DrawOptions(screen)

bulletList = []
playerList = []
environmentList = []
arbiterList = []

b0 = space.static_body
segmentBot = pymunk.Segment(b0, (0,height), (width, height), 4)
segmentTop = pymunk.Segment(b0, (0,0), (width, 0), 4)
segmentLef = pymunk.Segment(b0, (width,0), (width, height), 4)
segmentRit = pymunk.Segment(b0, (0,0), (0, height), 4)
walls = [segmentBot,segmentLef,segmentRit,segmentTop]

for i in walls:
  i.elasticity = 1
  i.friction = 0.5
  i.color = (255,255,255,255)
  environmentList.append(i)

class Player(object):
  radius = 30
  def __init__(self, position, space, color):
    self.body = pymunk.Body(mass=5,moment=10)
    self.mode = 0 # 0 is gun, 1 is thrust, ? 2 is shield
    self.body.position = position
    self.shape = pymunk.Circle(self.body, radius = self.radius)
    #self.image
    #self.shape.friction = 0.9
    self.shape.elasticity= 0.2
    space.add(self.body,self.shape)
    self.angleGun = 0
    self.angleThrust = 0
    self.health = 100
    self.speed = 500
    self.gearAngle = 0
    self.turningSpeed = 5
    self.shape.body.damping = 1000
    self.cooldown = 0
    self.fireRate = 30
    self.shape.collision_type = 1
    self.shape.color = color
    playerList.append(self)
  
  def force(self,force):
    self.shape.body.apply_force_at_local_point(force,(0,0))

  def rocketForce(self):
    radians = self.angleThrust * math.pi/180
    self.shape.body.apply_force_at_local_point((-self.speed * math.cos(radians),-self.speed * math.sin(radians)),(0,0))

  def draw(self):
    gear = pygame.image.load("gear.png")
    gearBox = gear.get_rect(center=self.shape.body.position)
    gearRotated = pygame.transform.rotate(gear, self.gearAngle)
    #gearRotated.rect.center=self.shape.body.position
    x,y = self.shape.body.position
    radianGun = self.angleGun * math.pi/180
    radianThrust = self.angleThrust * math.pi/180
    radiyus = 30 *(100-self.health)/100
    screen.blit(gearRotated,gearBox)
    self.gearAngle += 1
    if radiyus == 30:
      radiyus = 32
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,self.shape.color,self.shape.body.position,radiyus,0)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(0,0,0),self.shape.body.position,radiyus,0)
    pygame.draw.line(
      screen,(0,255,0), 
      (self.radius * math.cos(radianGun) * 1.5 + x,self.radius * math.sin(radianGun) * 1.5 + y),
      (x,y), 5
      )
    pygame.draw.line(
      screen,(200,200,0), 
      (self.radius * math.cos(radianThrust) * 1.5 + x,self.radius * math.sin(radianThrust) * 1.5 + y),
      (x,y), 5
      )
    #more
  
  def targetAngleGun(self,tAngle):
    tempTAngle = tAngle - self.angleGun
    tempTAngle = tempTAngle % 360
    if(tempTAngle < 180 and not tempTAngle == 0):
      self.angleGun -= self.turningSpeed
    elif(tempTAngle >= 180 and not tempTAngle == 0):
      self.angleGun += self.turningSpeed
    self.angleGun = self.angleGun % 360
    #print(tAngle, "target Angle")
    #print(self.angleGun, "selfangleGun")
    #print(tempTAngle, "tempTAngle")

  def targetAngleThrust(self,tAngle):
    tempTAngle = tAngle - self.angleThrust
    tempTAngle = tempTAngle % 360
    if(tempTAngle < 180 and not tempTAngle == 0):
      self.angleThrust -= self.turningSpeed
    elif(tempTAngle >= 180 and not tempTAngle == 0):
      self.angleThrust += self.turningSpeed
    self.angleThrust = self.angleThrust % 360
    #print(tAngle, "target Angle")
    #print(self.angleThrust, "selfangleGun")
    #print(tempTAngle, "tempTAngle")

  def targetAngle(self,tAngle):
    if(self.mode == 0):
      self.targetAngleGun(tAngle)
    elif(self.mode == 1):
      self.targetAngleThrust(tAngle)

  def shoot(self):
    if(self.cooldown == self.fireRate):
      x,y = self.shape.body.position
      radianGun = self.angleGun * math.pi/180
      spawnSpot = (self.radius * math.cos(radianGun) * 1.5 + x,self.radius * math.sin(radianGun)*1.5+y)
      self.shape.body.apply_impulse_at_local_point((-20 * math.cos(radianGun),-20 * math.sin(radianGun)),(0,0))
      print(spawnSpot)
      bT = Bullet(spawnSpot, 5, 50,self.shape.color)
      b = copy.deepcopy(bT)
      bulletList.append(b)
      space.add(b.shape,b.shape.body)
      b.getShot(self.angleGun)
      self.cooldown = 0
      print('pew')
      shoot_fx.play()
     # HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

  def tick(self): 
    self.draw()
    if(self.cooldown < self.fireRate):
      self.cooldown += 1
    #for o in playerList:
    #  c = self.shape.shapes_collide(o.shape)
    #  if(len(c.points)>0):
    #    self.damage(c.points[0].distance/10)
    for o in bulletList:
      c = self.shape.shapes_collide(o.shape)
      #print(c)
    for o in walls:
      c = self.shape.shapes_collide(o)
      if(len(c.points)>0):
        self.damage(c.points[0].distance * 3)
      
  def damage(self, damage):
    self.health -= abs(damage)
    if self.health < 0:
      self.health = 0

#maybe make it part of the player class
def drawWallCollision(arbiter, space, data):
  for c in arbiter.contact_point_set.points:
    r = max(3, abs(c.distance * 5))
    r = int(r)
    p = tuple(map(int, c.point_a))
    pygame.draw.circle(data["surface"], pygame.Color("red"), p, r, 0)
    print('magnitude', math.sqrt(arbiter.total_impulse[0]**2 + arbiter.total_impulse[1]**2))
    #print('position',  p)
    #print(data)
  print("its all arbitrary")
  s1, s2 = arbiter.shapes
  collision_fx.play()

def drawBulletCollision(arbiter, space, data):
  s1, s2 = arbiter.shapes 
  for c in arbiter.contact_point_set.points:
    magnitude = math.sqrt(arbiter.total_impulse[0]**2 + arbiter.total_impulse[1]**2)
    for p in playerList:
      avr = ((c.point_a[0] + c.point_b[0])/2, (c.point_a[1] + c.point_b[1])/2)
      distance  = (math.sqrt((avr[0] - p.shape.body.position[0]) **2 + (avr[1] - p.shape.body.position[1]) **2 ))
      if(distance < Bullet.explosionRadius + Player.radius):
        if not(s1.color == s2.color):
          p.damage(magnitude)
      for b in bulletList:
        avr = ((c.point_a[0] + c.point_b[0])/2, (c.point_a[1] + c.point_b[1])/2)
        distance  = (math.sqrt((avr[0] - p.shape.body.position[0]) **2 + (avr[1] - p.shape.body.position[1]) **2 ))
        if(distance < Bullet.explosionRadius + Player.radius):
          if not(s1.color == s2.color):
            b.damage(magnitude)
    pygame.draw.circle(data["surface"], pygame.Color("red"), tuple(map(int, c.point_a)), 10, 0)
    print('magnitude', magnitude)
    #print('position',  p)
    #print(data)
  print("its all arbitrary")
  
def drawArbitraryCollision(arbiter, space, data):
  collision_fx.play()

class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load("gear.png")
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = [x, y]

  def rotate(self):
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image,1)



class Bullet(object):
  damage = 2
  explosionRadius = 5
  def __init__(self, position, size, speed,color):
    pts = [(-size, -size), (size, -size), (size, size), (-size, size)]
    self.body = copy.deepcopy(pymunk.Body(mass=0.1,moment=1))
    self.shape = copy.deepcopy(pymunk.Poly(self.body, pts))
    self.shape.body.position = position
    self.shape.friction = 0.5
    self.shape.elasticity = 1
    self.shape.color = color
    self.speed = speed
    self.size = size
    self.shape.collision_type = 2
    #space.add(self.body,self.shape)
    #bulletList.append(self)
    self.lifetime = 0

  def getShot(self,angle):
    radians = angle * math.pi/180
    self.shape.body.apply_impulse_at_local_point((self.speed * math.cos(radians),self.speed * math.sin(radians)),(0,0))

  def tick(self):
    self.lifetime += 1
    if(self.lifetime > 300):
      self.shape.body.position = (10000,30)

  def damage(self, damage):
    self.lifetime = 300



  #VELOCITY OF BULLET STARTS WITH VELOCITY OF PLAYER
  #MAKE VOLUME OF SOUND DEPEND ON THE IMPULSE FOR THE IMPACTS
  #error on purpose so you notice this

  #INSTANCES NOT WORKING????
  
 
def runPyGame():
  # Initialise PyGame.
  pygame.init()

 

  # Set up the clock. This will tick every frame and thus maintain a relatively constant framerate. Hopefully.
  fps = 60.0
  fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
  
  running = True
  font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 16)
  

  p1 = Player((240,240),space,(132, 66, 245,255))
  p2 = Player((1200,400),space,(47, 247, 184,255))

  space.add(segmentBot,segmentTop,segmentLef,segmentRit)
  # Main game loop.

  ch = space.add_collision_handler(1, 0)
  ch.data["surface"] = screen
  ch.post_solve = drawWallCollision

  ch = space.add_collision_handler(1, 2)
  ch.data["surface"] = screen 
  ch.post_solve = drawBulletCollision

  ch = space.add_collision_handler(0, 2)
  ch.data["surface"] = screen 
  ch.post_solve = drawArbitraryCollision


  dt = 1/fps # dt is the time since last frame.
  while True: # Loop forever!
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      # We need to handle these events. Initially the only one you'll want to care
      # about is the QUIT event, because if you don't handle it, your game will crash
      # whenever someone tries to exit.
      if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit() # Opposite of pygame.init
        sys.exit() # Not including this line crashes the script on Windows. 
      if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
          p1.mode = -(p1.mode - 0.5) + 0.5
          print(p1.mode)
        if (event.key == pygame.K_k and p1.mode == 0):
          p1.shoot()
        if event.key == pygame.K_KP_5:
          p2.mode = -(p2.mode - 0.5) + 0.5
          print(p2.mode)
        if (event.key == pygame.K_m and p2.mode == 0):
          p2.shoot()
          #b = Bullet((200,200),51,51)
    if(keys[K_w]):
      p1.targetAngle(90)
    if(keys[K_q]):
      p1.targetAngle(45)
    if(keys[K_a]):
      p1.targetAngle(0)
    if(keys[K_z]):
      p1.targetAngle(315)
    if(keys[K_x]):
      p1.targetAngle(270)
    if(keys[K_c]):
      p1.targetAngle(225)
    if(keys[K_d]):
      p1.targetAngle(180)
    if(keys[K_e]):
      p1.targetAngle(135)
    if(keys[K_k] and p1.mode == 1):
      p1.rocketForce()
    if(keys[K_KP_8]):
      p2.targetAngle(90)
    if(keys[K_KP_7]):
      p2.targetAngle(45)
    if(keys[K_KP_4]):
      p2.targetAngle(0)
    if(keys[K_KP_1]):
      p2.targetAngle(315)
    if(keys[K_KP_2]):
      p2.targetAngle(270)
    if(keys[K_KP_3]):
      p2.targetAngle(225)
    if(keys[K_KP_6]):
      p2.targetAngle(180)
    if(keys[K_KP_9]):
      p2.targetAngle(135)
    if(keys[K_m] and p2.mode == 1):
      p2.rocketForce()
      # Handle other events as you wish.

    screen.fill((250, 250, 250)) # Fill the screen with black.

    # Redraw screen here.
    ### Draw stuff
        
    draw_bg()
    space.debug_draw(draw_options)
    
    for i in playerList:
      i.tick()

    screen.blit(
      font.render("P1 Health: " + str(p1.health), True, pygame.Color("white")),
      (50, 10),
    )
    screen.blit(
      font.render("P2 Health: " + str(p2.health), True, pygame.Color("white")),
      (50, 30),
    )
    for i in bulletList:
      i.tick()

    ship_group.draw(screen)
    # Flip the display so that the things we drew actually show up.
    pygame.display.update()

    
    dt = fpsClock.tick(fps)
    space.step(0.01)
  
  pygame.display.update()

runPyGame()
```

Comment: Could you make a [mcve]? Both M and R are critical.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I cant point to the exact error since the code is quite long and depends on files I dont have. But here is a general advice for troubleshooting:

Try to give a name to each shape when you create them, and then print it out. Also print out the name of each shape that you add or remove from the space. This should show which shape you are actually removing and will probably make it easy to understand whats wrong.

For example:

```
...
self.shape = pymunk.Circle(self.body, radius = self.radius)
self.shape.name = "circle 1"
print("Created", self.shape.name)
...
print("Adding", self.shape.name)
space.add(self.body,self.shape)
...
```

(Note that you need to reset the name of shapes you copy, since otherwise the copy will have the same name.)